# I want to grab the username of each seller on this poshmark webpage using javascript, cheerio, and axiom

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, cheerio, axiom

I've tried a lot of different things, and this seems to be the closest, but it only returns one of the div items i looking for...

I've gotten it to return multiple, BUT whenever it does return multiple divs - It returns blank list when i try to call the .text() function on the html and enter it into list *(I've since deleted that code.)*

Here is the webpage, and if you check every single item box has a seller name. I've tried for about 5 hours now, and im obviously a beginner especially in JS so it's been a good challenge. I think im lacking some fundamental knowledge which is holding me back.

https://poshmark.com/category/Men-Jackets_&_Coats?sort_by=like_count&all_size=true&my_size=false

Thank you to everyone who offers help. Happy holidays.

```
const express = require("express");
const cheerio = require("cheerio");
const request = require("request-promise");
const pretty = require("pretty");
const { default: axios } = require("axios");
const app = express();
const port = process.env.port || 5000;

let states =[];

const url = "https://poshmark.com/category/Men-Jackets_&_Coats?sort_by=like_count&all_size=true&my_size=false";

const fetchData = async () => {

    try {
        let res = await axios.get(url);
        let $ = await cheerio.load(res.data);

        const items = $("#content > div > div > div > div:nth-child(4) > section > div.tiles_container.m--t--1");      

        const itemArea = $("#content > div > div > div > div:nth-child(4) > section > div.tiles_container.m--t--1 > div:nth-child(1) > div > div")

        itemArea.each(function(i){
            itemHref = itemArea.find("href").text()
            areaText = itemArea.text();
            console.log(areaText);

            console.log(itemHref);

            //console.log(`${i} : ${itemArea}\n\n\n`)
        });
        
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
        return
    }
};

fetchData();
```

I tried grabbing the href and grabbing the class with the username at the bottom of each div, and each time it returned blank or undefined once i thought i finally got it.

Answer (score 0):

It may just be an issue with your selector. however, I found that this works:

```
const itemArea = $(".tiles_container a.tile__creator span");

itemArea.each(function (i, element) {
    console.log('username: ', $(element).text());
});
```

this way we get only the user name in the text and not the entire card text.

Comment: Damn thanks it worked. I need to brush up on html and js scraping it seems. Completely new to it.